# create ubuntu server user with only read/write permissions for home directory

Tags: ubuntu-server

I would like to create some users on my ubuntu server.  I only want to let the users have read/write access to their home directories, and not be able to read or write to any other user's home directory.  Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this?  Like is there a way to create a group that has these permissions and then add all the users to the group?  Or do I need to create each user, and just grant them only read/write permission on their home directory?  I'm new to ubuntu server and when I create a new user, it seems to have all the same permissions that my account does.

Answer (score 0):

First, this question is better suited for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), the stack exchange site specifically for ubuntu questions.

To answer your question, I'd recommend reading the [ubuntu article on user management](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html), everything you need to know is there. Here are the relevant sections:

> To add or delete a personalized group, use the following syntax,
>   respectively:
>
> ```
> sudo addgroup groupname
> sudo delgroup groupname
> ```
>
> To add a user to a group, use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> sudo adduser username groupname
> ```
>
> ---
>
> When a new user is created, the adduser utility creates a brand new
>   home directory named /home/username. The default profile is modeled
>   after the contents found in the directory of /etc/skel, which includes
>   all profile basics.
>
> If your server will be home to multiple users, you should pay close
>   attention to the user home directory permissions to ensure
>   confidentiality. By default, user home directories in Ubuntu are
>   created with world read/execute permissions. This means that all users
>   can browse and access the contents of other users home directories.
>   This may not be suitable for your environment.
>
> To verify your current user home directory permissions, use the
>   following syntax:
>
> ```
> ls -ld /home/username
> ```
>
> The following output shows that the directory /home/username has
>   world-readable permissions:
>
> ```
> drwxr-xr-x  2 username username    4096 2007-10-02 20:03 username
> ```
>
> You can remove the world readable-permissions using the following
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 0750 /home/username
> ```
>
> A much more efficient approach to the matter would be to modify the
>   adduser global default permissions when creating user home folders.
>   Simply edit the file /etc/adduser.conf and modify the DIR_MODE
>   variable to something appropriate, so that all new home directories
>   will receive the correct permissions.
>
> ```
> DIR_MODE=0750
> ```
>
> After correcting the directory permissions using any of the previously
>   mentioned techniques, verify the results using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> ls -ld /home/username
> ```
>
> The results below show that world-readable permissions have been
>   removed:
>
> ```
> drwxr-x---   2 username username    4096 2007-10-02 20:03 username
> ```